# Is Outlier detection in two separate databases is equal to one combined database?

Tags: outliers, mathematical-statistics, database

Suppose that we have two databases : `Database_1` and `Database_2` . `Database_1` has 300 samples and `Database_2` has 700 samples. `Database_all` is combination of two databases.

- Is finding outliers using `abs(X-mean(X))>=1.9*std(X)` in `Database_all` is equal to finding outliers separately in `Database_1` and `Database_2`? In both cases we will remove same samples or not?
- Suppose that we will remove outliers with column 1 on above databases. In column `2` and `3` we have data that we want create a label for every sample like this `(column_2_value-column_3_value)/mean(column_2)` (`mean(column_2)` is average of all values in column `2`) We want calculate this label for all samples after removing outliers. In this case we have same label values if we remove outliers from `Database_all` compare to calculate after removing outliers separately in `Database_89` and `Database_90`?

Please mathematically prove this problem if you have time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. for the rule you're applying, identifying outliers separately is not the same as doing them combined.

   Proof by counterexample:

   X1:

   ```
   0.9370 0.4682 1.5110 0.9823 0.7902 0.4803 2.6851 1.3149 0.8814 0.1704

                                              ^^^^
   ```

   X2:

   ```
   8.7947 9.5796 9.9795 9.7903 8.6101 9.5739 8.5613 9.5829 9.1885 7.6370

                                                                   ^^^^
   ```

   The "outliers" in the individual groups are marked by `^^^^`.

   The combined data has no outliers.

   For example, in R:

   ```
   x1 =c(0.9370, 0.4682, 1.5110, 0.9823, 0.7902, 0.4803, 2.6851, 1.3149, 0.8814, 0.1704)
   x2 =c(8.7947, 9.5796, 9.9795, 9.7903, 8.6101, 9.5739, 8.5613, 9.5829, 9.1885, 7.6370)

   # x1 outliers at obs #:
    which(abs(scale(x1)) >=1.9)
   [1] 7

   # x2 outliers at obs #:
    which(abs(scale(x2)) >=1.9)
   [1] 10

   # combine data
    x12=c(x1,x2)

   # any combined-sample outliers?
    any(abs(scale(x12)) >=1.9)
   [1] FALSE
   ```
2. If I understood correctly (I found the wording confusing) the answer here is also no, since the answer in (1) was "no".